# Android HelloGallery Example

Tags: android, android-gallery, android-gridview, styleable

im working on a HelloGallery example for an Android app i'm developing. I need to display two pictures from my res/drawable-hdpi and I'm doing this via the *HelloGallery* examples on the web. I tried using the HelloViews ( http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/index.html ) on the Android developers website but apparently they're outdated since the Android 1.5 update. I'm developing my app on 2.1 and res.styleable no longer exists apparently. Then I decided to look in other places and found a really good example on the following website: http://www.androidpeople.com/android-gallery-imageview-example. After making a **resources.xml** and **styles.xml** under **res/values**, it comes up with one error on this part.

```
TypedArray typArray = obtainStyledAttributes(R.styleable.GalleryTheme);
GalItemBg = typArray.getResourceId(R.styleable.GalleryTheme_android_galleryItemBackground, 0);
```

The errors are :

> GalleryTheme cannot be resolved or is not a field AND
>   GalleryTheme_android_galleryItemBackground cannot be resolved or is
>   not a field

ANY KIND OF HELP WOULD BE MUCH APPRECIATED as i've been working on this forever. Thanks a lot! Also, a *HelloGallery* that works and displays the pictures in the **res/drawable-hdpi** would also be a good alternative / EXTREMELY HELPFUL. THANKS A LOT!

Comment: What do you need the styles for? To me it looks like you want to learn how a gallery is used. For that you do not need any styles.

Comment: I agree with JSydow, first try making the gallery without styles and see if it works

Comment: Ok, thanks for the advice. Do you know any websites that could guide me through a good gallery tutorial for android 2.1? The only ones i can find are 1.5 and below :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The R class, where your values `R.styleable.GalleryTheme` and `R.styleable.GalleryTheme_android_galleryItemBackground` are being retrieved from, contains a class per xml file (kinda)

So for example if you have your GalleryTheme stored in styles.xml you can access it using `R.style.GalleryTheme`.

Folder                       R class
Drawable                     R.drawable.*
Drawablehdpi                 R.drawable.*
Drawableldpi                 R.drawable.*
Drawablemdpi                 R.drawable.*
Layouts.xml                  R.layout.*
Colours.xml                  R.colour.*

etc

Comment: Doing that from memory btw so don't take it as gospel.